# Android ndk profiling: error: undefined reference to 'monstartup'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, profiling

I am attempting to profile a mixed C/C++ android project in eclipse. I am following the instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/wiki/Usage).

I unzipped the android-ndk-profiler-v3.2.zip into "c:\android_profiler\", i.e. we have a directory "c:\android_profiler\android-ndk-profiler\" containing prof.h, android.mk and two sub-directories, armeabi and armeabi-v7a.

I added `#include "c:\android_profiler\android-ndk-profiler\prof.h"` to the start of my C++ source, as well as adding calls to monstartup() and moncleanup(). When I attempt to build the project I get `error: undefined reference to 'monstartup'` appearing in my "problems" tab. Looking online, the consensus is that this error is a link failure caused by an incorrect setting of LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES in my project's android.mk, but I have tried every variation I can think of, including the following (tried one at a time), but none of them fixed the error. Any other ideas?

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c:/android_profiler/android-ndk-profiler
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c:/android_profiler/android-ndk-profiler/armeabi-v7a/libandroid-ndk-profiler.a
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c:\android_profiler\android-ndk-profiler
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android-ndk-profiler
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_profiler
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c:/android_profiler
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := c:\android_profiler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

Seems it was just the location of the line `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android-ndk-profiler` within android.mk. I moved it to a later point in the file and hey presto - it all worked.